# Merging several images using VBA

Tags: excel, image, vba, merge, png

I have several images that I'm querying from a database. All of those files are in `.png`.

My current process involves downloading each image and then align them next to each other without space in between. It would be possible to stack them as well if that makes the process easier.

I am now looking for a way to take the images and basically save the file as a Picture as if they were a grouped item in Excel.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I have looked around and I've found something that did this with TIFF but that's not exactly what I have here and I wasn't able to adapt the code.

Comment: To be clear you want one image to follow the next to create one large .png file?

Comment: Correct, they are like a puzzle and I want to combine the pieces to a single puzzle and save it.

Comment: Have you looked [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/), there is so much to consider, I was going to alter some code I have that generates PNGs on the fly, but the odds of it working in your case are quite small. Its possible, but you would need to understand the PNG file format.